# Porting obj-c delegate method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

Ho do I port this optional obj-c delegate method to swift?

```
- (void)popupStoreEventWasEmitted:(PopupStoreController *)controller withEvent:(NSString*)eventName withPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload;
```

I have tried every possible combination of AnyObject (optional and required), NSDictionary, Dictionary (optional and required), String and NSString (optional and required), etc. etc. But no matter what it states the err:

/FastDev/Classes/TDTFinishingViewController.swift:884:14: Objective-C method 'popupStoreEventWasEmitted:withEvent:withPayload:' provided by method 'popupStoreEventWasEmitted(:withEvent:withPayload:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'popupStoreEventWasEmitted(:withEvent:withPayload:)' in protocol 'PopupStoreControllerDelegate'

Is there any place I can look to find what the swift delegate method looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just start typing the method name, Xcode should autocomplete it for you. I get:

```
func popupStoreEventWasEmitted(controller: PopupStoreController!,
                               withEvent eventName: String!,
                               withPayload payload: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{

}
```

Comment: Yeah, what is odd is I don't get any auto complete (thats usually how I do it), and I get an error if I try to import with "import PopUpLib" in my Swift ViewController (but I do have the headers imported in my bridging header). Other than this - everything works. Anyhow - that works for me. Thanks!